# Extract a non-matching portion of a string using stringr and lookahead

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a string which always contains unwanted text at the end. I would like to extract everything but the unwanted text.

```
text <- "my_text_and_unwanted_text"
output <- str_extract(text, ".*(?=<_and)")
output
```

I am hoping that ".*" matches all text that precedes anything with "_and". So the intended result is "my text" but I get "NA". I have reviewed a number of posts but having trouble finding examples that show how to match everything but the desired string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think of this operation is to replace the unwanted text with nothing rather than extract everything else. This is often simpler.

```
text <- "my_text_and_unwanted_text"
str_replace(text, "_and.*", "")
# [1] "my_text"
```

For the extracting approach, your attempt was very close. `(?<=` is for look-*behind*, you need `(?=` for look-*ahead*

```
str_extract(text, ".*(?=_and)")
# [1] "my_text"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing the problem. Instead of extracting the text you want, remove the text you do not want:

```r
str_remove(text, "_and.*")
[1] "my_text"
```